# django multisite with only one wgsi file

Tags: django, wsgi

I'm using a virtual dedicated server which allow not to change apache virtual hosts. So I'm stuck with only one wsgi file.

There is few doc about multisite in django, so I believe the answer to my question is NO, but I prefere to be sure : is there any way to declare more than one website inside a wsgi file ? Or must I use some middleware ?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change the VirtualHost at all then you may not get very far. You at least need to be able to add additional ServerAlias directives to the VirtualHost such that the extra hostnames get mapped to that WSGI application. If they are all a sub domain then a wildcard can be used, but you still need to be able to add the wildcard ServerAlias for sub domains to the VirtualHost.

Comment: Thanks for replying. All host are redirected the same way, so the server is configured the wildcard way. Question is how to use, with one lone wsgi file, several subdomain on it, since I can't made vhost specific wsgi.